# How is the Android API documentation generated and is a documentation style guide and templates available?

Tags: android, doxygen, android-sdk-tools

I'd like to make API documentation from source code similar to the documentation style used by the [Andorid API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity).
I've searched around but didn't find any mention of the tools used - however, I'm assuming it's derived from Doxygen and that the documentation is extracted from the source code.

So my questions are:

1. Exactly what tools are used to generate those pages?
2. Is the Android API documentation style guides that were used to make those pages available?
3. Is the template that's used to generate those pages available for inspiration?

Comment: Page doesn't look like to be generated by doxygen. Why do you think it was? Some hints you might find in, the to me unknown, android repository.

Comment: @albert The documentation looks like it’s generated by something with a deep insight into the source, but I’m not sure by what tool: that’s why I’m asking for help identifying it. I’m not saying it’s Doxygen, but probably a tool derived (perhaps only in spirit) from Doxygen.